# Como mapear um Map no Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Estou tentando mapear um diário para um aprendiz, onde no diário eu tenho um `Map<data,mensagem>`, ou seja, a data que foi criada e sua respectiva mensagem, porém com o mapeamento que fiz, acabo tomando o seguinte erro:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: 
  Foreign key (FKr7nhfmr8w22h0h9ggc2oxd33r:aprendiz [diario_id])) must have same 
  number of columns as the referenced primary key (diario [id,data])
```

Classe Aprendiz:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Aprendiz extends Pessoa {

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Diario diario;

    //get, set, hashcode...
}
```

Classe Diario

```
@Entity
public class Diario implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "diario")
    private Aprendiz aprendiz;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "data")
    @Column(name = "texto")
    @CollectionTable(name = "diario", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    private Map<LocalDate, String> entrada = new HashMap<>();

        //get, set, hashcode...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um `converter` para converter os dados de maneira que o JPA consiga interpretá-lo:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JpaConverterJson implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, String>, String> {

    private final static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JpaConverterJson.class);

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<String, String> meta) {
        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(meta);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.warn("Error convert JpaConverterJson@convertToDatabaseColumn " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if (dbData != null) {
            try {
                return mapper.readValue(dbData, Map.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.warn("Error convert JpaConverterJson@convertToEntityAttribute " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return new HashMap<>();
    }

}
```

E chamá-lo via Annotation:

```
@Convert(converter = JpaConverterJson.class)
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "data")
    @Column(name = "texto")
    @CollectionTable(name = "diario", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    private Map<LocalDate, String> entrada = new HashMap<>();
```

Links que podem ajudar:
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters